# Combining csv files horizontally

Tags: c#, csv

I have a little project that I want to complete in C#, I'm no expert but I haven't been able to find any other solutions for what I'm trying to do so maybe I just don't know what to look for.

I have several csv files set out like this;

```
  | AColumn  | BColumn
--+----------+---------
1 | Title    |
--+----------+---------
2 | Year     |
--+----------+---------
3 | Heading1 | Heading2
--+----------+---------
4 | DATA1    | DATA2
```

What I'd like to do (and I'm not sure if I even can) is to combine them like but append the information horizontally.

For example appending two would look like the below;

```
  | AColumn  | BColumn  | CColumn  | Dcolumn
--+----------+----------+----------+---------
1 | Title    |          |          |
--+----------+----------+----------+---------
2 | Year     |          |          |
--+----------+----------+----------+---------
3 | Heading1 | Heading2 | Heading3 | Heading4 
--+----------+----------+----------+---------
4 | DATA1    | DATA2    | DATA3    | DATA4
```

The code I have already successfully deletes the title and year aside from the first file but it add the other files to the bottom.

Hopefully this is enough information but I'm around to add more if you need.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;


class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog
        {
            ShowNewFolderButton = false
        };

        string selectedFolder = @"C:\";
        folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = selectedFolder;

        //If OK is pressed
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Grab the folder that was chosen
            selectedFolder = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            //get all csv files
            string[] filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(selectedFolder, "*.csv");
            //create combined directory
            Directory.CreateDirectory(selectedFolder + "\\Combined\\");
            //define it as destination folder
            string destinationFolder = selectedFolder + "\\Combined\\";
            //define destination file name
            string destinationFile = "Combined.csv";

            StreamWriter fileDest = new StreamWriter(destinationFolder + destinationFile, true);
            for (int i = 0; i < filepaths.Length; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    string file = filepaths[i];
                    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        lines = lines.Skip(1).ToArray(); // Skip header row for all but first file
                    }

                    foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        fileDest.WriteLine(line);
                        Console.WriteLine(file);
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //nothing so far
                }
            }
            fileDest.Close();
            Console.Write("Press Enter to close");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your data only on fourth row? If not, what if different files have different number of data rows?

Comment: Why the `excel` tag? `csv` is just a text file. If you want to combine *lines*, read lines from both sources and match them one by one

Comment: BTW csvs use commas. You posted ASCII art instead, similar to RestructuredText tables. Are the files CSV or RST?

Comment: You should always use a proper library for csv handling. Real-world csv files can contain quotes, delimiters and even line breaks inside values (properly enclosed in quotes of course). Any of these vanilla approaches will break easily in such cases.

Comment: So many question. Are those original "Csv" have a know numbers of column, are those strict enought to be consider?  Every file have title and years.. what happend to those in the combined file? Numbers of lines must match, if not : null in column where we don't have data or drop the lines?

Comment: What is the type of Data? I mean simple solution spliting on commas will not work if one field is a string or a decimal.. because string can has comaa in it and decimal sperator can be comma with some culture.

Comment: And for column with the same name, with same or different data how do you handle those?

Comment: The most naive approach will be once you got all the header add them as `Columns` of a `DataTable`, then adding data is the right cell reading files after files will be easy as long as you don't have many column with the same name...

Comment: Thanks guys. They are csv sorry about the excel tag. 
Number of rows vary into the 100k mark and there are two fixed columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple solution:

```
// first put data of all files in a list:
List<string[]> fileData = new List<string[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < filepaths.Length; i++)
{
    string file = filepaths[i];
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
    fileData.Add(lines);
}
//then combine them horizontally in another list
List<string> combined = new List<string>();
var maxCount = fileData.Max(x=>x.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < maxCount ; i++)
{
    combined.Add(string.Join(",", fileData.Select(x => x.Length > i ? x[i] : "")));
}
```

then you can write the combined data into destination file using `File.WriteAllLines()`